# How to unblock recv() or recvfrm() function in linux C

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I want to send a UDP packet to a camera from the PC when the PC resumes from sleep. Since it takes some time (unknown) to the network interface to become alive after the PC resumes, I keep sending packets to the camera in a loop. When the camera receives the packet, it sends an acknowledge signal to the PC.
My problem is "for receiving the UDP packet from the camera (ack signal), I use recvfrm() function which blocks the loop. How do I unblock this function so that it exit the loop only when it receives acknowledge signal from the camera.

Comment: MSG_DONTWAIT does the job but with another minor problem. I send the packets to camera in a loop before the network becomes alive. As soon as the network becomes alive, the packet is received by the camera and an acknowledge signal is sent back to the PC. The problem is that before the PC gets an acknowledge signal and exits the loop, it still sends a few packets to the camera which are buffered somewhere. Next time, the camera doesn't waits for the packets from the PC, but rather reads the old packets which is unacceptable. How do I avoid such situation? How do I flush/clear the old packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more portable solution to maverik's answer (which is otherwise correct) would be to `fcntl` the socket to `O_NONBLOCK`.

`MSG_DONTWAIT`, although available under Linux and BSD and most Unices is only standardized in SUSv4 for sending (why, I wouldn't know... but M. Kerrisk says so). One notable platform which doesn't support it is Winsock (at least it's not documented in MSDN).

Alternatively, if you don't want to tamper with obscure flags and `fcntl`, you could `select` the descriptor for readiness (with a zero timeout, or even with a non-zero timeout to throttle the packets you send -- it's probably a good idea not to flood the network stack). Keep sending until `select` says something can be read.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag passed to `recvfrom` function. It enables non-blocking mode. If the operation would block this call returns `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (but not the nicest code) is to wait for a while on a reply is to use [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) before calling recvfrom().